# Error 404 POST form data from react to express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to post data from a form (react) to my backend (nodejs/express), but I am getting a 404 error. There is a lot of code here, so I've tried to post just what is important.

Function to submit

```
  //submit data
  const submitCard = (ev) => {
    console.log(ev);
    ev.preventDefault();

    try {
      api.post('/api/stripe/', payment).then((result) => {
        window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

data being submitted

```
  const paymentUpdated = () => {
    setPayment({
      name: name,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      cardNumber: number,
      expDate: expiry,
      cvc: cvc,
      zip: zip,
      plan: plan,
    });
  };
```

form tag + button

```
<form className="creditForm" onSubmit={submitCard}>
<Button className="save-button" type="submit">
```

route being submitted to (still need send data to stripe)

```
 app.post('/api/stripe', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const plan = await stripe.plans.retrieve('price_1HfAZGGFN31Q4RRjSrFXnGgD');
    console.log(req);
    if (req.user.stripeId) {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(req.user.stripeId);
    } else {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.user.email,
        description: 'Subscribing to Personal Plan Monthly Subscription',
      });
      req.user.stripeId = customer.id;
      const user = await req.user.save();
    }
    req.user.plan = 2;
    const user = await req.user.save();
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: req.user.stripeId,
      items: [{ price: 'price_1HfAZGGFN31Q4RRjSrFXnGgD' }],
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell if the request to ```/api/stripe/``` that is failing or is it the redirect?
Also, have you checked if the env variable ```REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI``` is set properly?

Comment: The /api/stripe/ is failing when I run it by itself because it needs the data from the form to be submitted so stripe can process it, but is still running until it gets to that point. When I submit form it is not running at all server side which is why I thought it was something to do with the function I was using to post. The 404 error I am getting has the correct port 'localhost:3500/api/stripe/ which is the route to express/nodejs

Comment: I am confused by the first snippet. By the first look it seems front end code but then you use process.env which is globally available in node. Also you never use what is returned by your promise. My assumption is that window.location.href is set to a url that does not have a route and that is potentially the cause of 404

Comment: The first 3 snippets were all code from the front end form component. I didn't know process.env was only for node. I have been using it with react as well and call that redirect in a few other places on the site. You may be right though, I am testing backend route with curl now and getting a different error(401), so after I resolve that I will try again without the results or the process.env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an inconsistency in the URL your **posting to** and that configured in **express**. Your posting to `/api/stripe/`, but express is setup to listen for `/api/stripe`, **note the lack of trailing** `/` in express. So it is not finding the endpoint you are expecting.

I tend to test my **API**s using `curl` commands e.g.

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3500/api/stripe/" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value 2"}'
```

Once I have proven the API works, only then do I worry about calling it from an app. This will make it easier to identify where the problem lies, in your code.

Comment: Yes, this looks correct. Verify that your API endpoint works first with manual curl or postman/insomnia requests, then build it into your app. Probably removing the extra `/` in your request `api.post('/api/stripe', ...)` will fix your issue.

Comment: Didn't think to do this, but I think it helped me solve the problem. It was with the requireLogin function I was using to make sure user was logged in before posting. It was referencing req.user but for some reason couldn't find it even when logged in. for now I removed it and it is working fine.